# how to check current date is between two dates in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table

```
    +---------------------+-----------
    | id | start_date     |  End_date |
    +---------------------+-----------+
    |   1  | 2017-07-07   | 2017-07-31|
    |   2  | 2017-08-01   | 2017-08-31|
    |   3  | 2017-09-01   | 2017-09-10|
    |  
    +------+--------------+-----------+
```

And I want to select dates between two dates.I have a query

```
 SELECT * FROM Financial_Year WHERE CURDATE() between `start_date` and `End_date`
```

I want to convert this query to laravel so i tried this

```
 $dt = Carbon::now();
 $getmonths= DB::table('Financial_Year')
                    ->whereBetween($dt, ['start_date', 'End_date'])->get();
```

But i didn't get output.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `End_date` should be `end_date` in your case probably ? is it typo or correct ?

Comment: @SagarGautam is it really a error..?? explain!!!

Comment: You have to do a `where(\DB::raw("$dt BETWEEN start_data and end_date"))` the query builder usually assumes the first parameter is a column name and the others are values but here its the other way around, If you do use a raw db query might as well use `CURDATE()` instead of carbon too.

Comment: Since, all code looks correct and you have not followed table name and column name convention. It should not be a problem though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you can use laravel **whereRaw()**  to achieve this.

Just like this

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$getmonths= DB::table('Financial_Year')
    ->whereRaw('"'.$dt.'" between `start_date` and `End_date`')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain why raw query works and laravel query not working ?

Comment: `where between` works only with numbers and not with dates

Comment: Actually  laravel query builder takes the data and operators or conditions and build an MySQL raw query for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Carbon native function for this:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
$first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 1);
$second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second));  // bool(true)
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second));  // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only Laravel Query Builder maybe you could try:

```
$date = Carbon::now();

$query = Model::where('start_date', '<=', $date)
        ->where('end_date', '>=', $date)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check a single user input date with two database columns

```
   ->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
     ->where('end_date', '>=', $date)->exists();
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)